# Bad level loading in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, restart

I'm currently making a game project in Unity 2D, and when I want to restart the level after death, it restarts, but only the old form of the map.

I tried to change the code and the level restarts, but unfortunately it's still on the non-updated map.

Answer (score 0):

By restarting, you reload the scene. So, everything is at default. If you want to restart the level but keeping the form of it, you should probably just change what you want to change. For example, if you want to keep the level but reset the players positions, just change it.